Hot Reloading Not Reflecting Changes After Commenting Out Console Logs
I tried console logging some data, and later I commented out those lines. However, even after hot reloading, the changes I made in the code were not reflected; they only appeared correctly after a hot restart.
Before changes
try {
      const config = {
        url: `${URLS.getPublicChannels}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const response = await MakeApiCall(config);
      console.log(response?.data?.response?.[2].title);
      console.log(response?.data?.response?.[5].title);
      this.setSearchResults(response || []);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching:", error);
    }

Output
Title 2
Title 5
After changes
try {
      const config = {
        url: `${URLS.getPublicChannels}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const response = await MakeApiCall(config);
      // console.log(response?.data?.response?.[2].title);
      // console.log(response?.data?.response?.[5].title);
      this.setSearchResults(response || []);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching:", error);
    }

Output
Title 2
Title 5
I tried clearing and disabling cache and I also tried using different browsers, but the issue persists.

Try running the npm run build or yarn build to clear cached build files and ensure the latest code is used

yeah bro, even tried that but the issue is not solved.
